# Unofficial tenancy contract UK visa

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas

I am renting a flat directly from the landlord, however this practice is pretty common where I live. The contract I have is non stamped. Is it okay to include an unofficial tenancy contract in a UK standard visitor visa application ?

Comment: What do you mean by "non stamped"?  In the UK, renting directly from a landlord is fairly normal, which usually simply means a signed tenancy agreement between landlord and tenant.

Comment: Does a "non stamped" contract have less legal standing or validity in the jurisdiction where you live?

Comment: I am not sure if it has a less value or not, but I am just wondering if it is ok

Comment: What is normal where you live? If your rental agreement should be stamped but is not then this might be a problem because you would look like someone who doesn't respect regulations and rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had numerous contracts with UK landlords over the years. They are signed by the landlord and myself and they are entirely official - that's to say legally binding.

I have no idea who you would expect to 'stamp' one of these, nor for what reason.

Such contracts are private agreements between you and the landlord and are nobody else's business. Only if a dispute arises and one of us sues the other do lawyers and courts get involved, and they will rule on who broke that terms of the contract and what restitution is required.